# What is this part of the hangman code doing?

Tags: python, list, function

I was looking at a code for a hangman game on python and I understand all of the code apart from a particular bit. Here's the code:

```
import random

# constants
HANGMAN = (
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |   -+-
 | 
 |   
 |   
 |   
 |   
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |  /-+-
 |   
 |   
 |   
 |   
 |   
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |  /-+-/
 |   
 |   
 |   
 |   
 |   
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |  /-+-/
 |    |
 |   
 |   
 |   
 |   
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |  /-+-/
 |    |
 |    |
 |   | 
 |   | 
 |   
----------
""",
"""
 ------
 |    |
 |    O
 |  /-+-/
 |    |
 |    |
 |   | |
 |   | |
 |  
----------
""")

MAX_WRONG = len(HANGMAN) - 1
WORDS = ("OVERUSED", "CLAM", "GUAM", "TAFFETA", "PYTHON")

# initialize variables
word = random.choice(WORDS)   # the word to be guessed
so_far = "-" * len(word)      # one dash for each letter in word to be guessed
wrong = 0                     # number of wrong guesses player has made
used = []                     # letters already guessed


print("Welcome to Hangman.  Good luck!")

while wrong < MAX_WRONG and so_far != word:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print("\nYou've used the following letters:\n", used)
    print("\nSo far, the word is:\n", so_far)

    guess = input("\n\nEnter your guess: ")
    guess = guess.upper()

    while guess in used:
        print("You've already guessed the letter", guess)
        guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
        guess = guess.upper()

    used.append(guess)

    if guess in word:
        print("\nYes!", guess, "is in the word!")

        # create a new so_far to include guess
        new = ""
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess == word[i]:
                new += guess
            else:
                new += so_far[i]              
        so_far = new

    else:
        print("\nSorry,", guess, "isn't in the word.")
        wrong += 1

if wrong == MAX_WRONG:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print("\nYou've been hanged!")
else:
    print("\nYou guessed it!")

print("\nThe word was", word)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Now what i don't understand is how the code ensures that every time you get a letter wrong, the man comes closer to getting hanged. Does it do this through the HANGMAN[wrong]? Also, why is wrong in square brackets, I can't see where a list called wrong was created...Could someone please explain the function of HANGMAN[wrong] please?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are right, a list is involved. The list in this case is called `HANGMAN` though, and `wrong` is the number of missed guesses so far.

So `print(HANGMAN[wrong])` selects the `wrong`-th entry from the large array in the beginning of your code and prints it.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. HANGMAN is the tuple and wrong-th entry will select the relevant element in the tuple. If wrong isn't a list, why is it in square brackets? Is it a syntax thing?

Comment: Yes, it's the Python way of accessing a list element. (Same syntax as in C and Java for example).